# Adicionar texto em linha especifica com repetição

Tags: delphi

Na imagem Abaixo temos o seguinte caso a pessoa digita nos dois campos de edit.
E clica em Gerar recomendação os valores são escrito em um *Tmemo.*
 O segundo passo seria pessoa digitar uma nova informação nos edits e ao clicar no botao ok a mesma deve ser adicionado abaixo da anterior e encima da linha `return dose`.
Só consigo inserir ou abaixo de todo o texto ou se eu definir a linha que o *Tmemo* vai escrever, ele sobreescreve quando tiver algo naquela linha

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Tmemo` possui a propriedade `LINES` que pode ser acessada diretamente.

Veja por exemplo:

```
var i : integer;
begin

  i := memo1.Lines.IndexOf('o texto antes escrito');
  Memo1.Lines.Delete[i];
  Memo1.Lines.Insert(i,'insere o novo texto');
end;
```

observe que a lista começa no índice 0 (zero)